# Select from query not functioning

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I just want to search data in my db but it is not functioning even if the data that I input in the textbox and comboBox has the correct data it keep show the else statement. it should be the else

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    searchWanted()
End Sub 

Public Sub searchWanted()
    Dim connString111 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=bin\Debug\record.accdb"
    MyConn111 = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn111.ConnectionString = connString111
    Try
        Dim mySQLCommand As New OleDbCommand("select from * mostwanted where FIRSTNAME = @b0 and MIDDLENAME = @b1 and LASTNAME = @b2 and QLFR = @b3", MyConn111)
        mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b0", FIRSTNAMETextBox.Text)
        mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", MIDDLENAMETextBox.Text)
        mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", LASTNAMETextBox.Text)
        mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b3", QLFRComboBox.SelectedItem)
        Dim da111 As New OleDbDataAdapter(mySQLCommand)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("This Person is Wanted")

            Dim picturedata As [Byte]() = table.Rows(0)(15)
            Using ms As New MemoryStream(picturedata)
                PHOTOPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
            End Using
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("This Person is CLEAN")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you never ever [fill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.7.2) your `table`.

Comment: `select * from`

Comment: still sir :( still same output

Comment: As mentioned, your table.Rows is always going to be zero since you didn't use the da111 adapter to fill the table with rows.

Comment: Edit your question to show the 2 fixes that you have acknowledged.